# Where to place json file inside my flutter iOS plugin

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, android-studio, flutter-plugin

I try to create iOS plugin for flutter. For that I want to use a json file, but I haven't managed to read it yet.

I don't know if I've placed my json file correctly in my project :

- At the root of ios folder
- Inside Assets folder of ios folder
- In assets folder of the root of my plugin project

Could you please explain me where to placed my json file.

I link you my function, in case I made a mistake in it.

Currently I call my loadSound function with packages/my_plugin/assets/sound.json filename.

Thanks for your help,

Best Regards,

```
struct Sound: Decodable {
    var id : String
    var title: String
    var uri: String
    var category: String

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "id": id,
            "title": title,
            "uri": uri,
            "category": category
        ]
    }
    var nsDictionary: NSDictionary {
        return dictionary as NSDictionary
    }
}

private func loadSound(filename: String) -> [Sound] {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let sounds = try decoder.decode([Sound].self, from: data)
                return sounds
            } catch {
                print("Error loading JSON data: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return []
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No, I do not get any error, juste a empty array after the call of the function loadSound. But I can't get the errors in the swift code, I only get the errors in the dart part.

Comment: Did you step through your function above to see what is happening?

Comment: Since I can't get any logs to appear in the runner, I don't really know what's going on. I've run several tests and this is the only function that can cause a problem.

Comment: You cannot use breakpoints?

Comment: I can't use breakpoint on swift code with android studio, because I don't have the redpoint next to my line of code

Comment: I don’t use android studio, sorry. I added it to the tags.

Comment: Ok np, Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: Run our project under Xcode so that you can use its debugger to debug the Swift code.

Comment: @Paulw11 How can I do that, because my swift code it's call by dart function ?

Comment: Just open the project in Xcode, set the breakpoint in the Swift line and then start the program from in Xcode. Do whatever you do in your app to trigger the call from dart to Swift and the the breakpoint will fire.

Comment: I tried to open my flutter plugin with xcode, but I have a warning "Could not open file or folder my_plugin", I also tried to just open the ios folder but I had the same warning. I can juste open my Swift file with xcode and I can't use xcode debugger with only one file.

Comment: Not the plug-in. Your app. There will be an Xcode project - probably Runner.xcworkscpace or similar

Comment: I try to launch my Runner with Xcode but my plugin module is not founded when I try to build

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your Flutter app setup and probably it isn't finding the plug-in when you run under Android studio either. When you run the iOS app under android studio it just runs the `xcodebuild` command line, so it should work under Xcode in the same. What happens if you run `flutter build ios` from the command line?